# Invalid header reading xls file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I am reading one excel file on my local system. I am using POI jar Version 3.7, but getting error Invalid header signature; 
read -2300849302551019537 or in Hex 0xE011BDBFEFBDBFEF , 
expected -2226271756974174256 or in Hex 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0.

Opening the xls file with Excel works fine.

The codeblock where it happens:
Anybody an idea ?

```
/**
 * create a new HeaderBlockReader from an InputStream
 *
 * @param stream the source InputStream
 *
 * @exception IOException on errors or bad data
 */
public HeaderBlockReader(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    // At this point, we don't know how big our
    //  block sizes are
    // So, read the first 32 bytes to check, then
    //  read the rest of the block
    byte[] blockStart = new byte[32];
    int bsCount = IOUtils.readFully(stream, blockStart);
    if(bsCount != 32) {
        throw alertShortRead(bsCount, 32);
    }

    // verify signature
    long signature = LittleEndian.getLong(blockStart, _signature_offset);

    if (signature != _signature) {
        // Is it one of the usual suspects?
        byte[] OOXML_FILE_HEADER = POIFSConstants.OOXML_FILE_HEADER;
        if(blockStart[0] == OOXML_FILE_HEADER[0] &&
            blockStart[1] == OOXML_FILE_HEADER[1] &&
            blockStart[2] == OOXML_FILE_HEADER[2] &&
            blockStart[3] == OOXML_FILE_HEADER[3]) {
            throw new OfficeXmlFileException("The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)");
        }
        if ((signature & 0xFF8FFFFFFFFFFFFFL) == 0x0010000200040009L) {
            // BIFF2 raw stream starts with BOF (sid=0x0009, size=0x0004, data=0x00t0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The supplied data appears to be in BIFF2 format.  "
                    + "POI only supports BIFF8 format");
        }

        // Give a generic error
        throw new IOException("Invalid header signature; read "
                              + longToHex(signature) + ", expected "
                              + longToHex(_signature));
    }
```

Comment: You are throwing this exception from your code? throw new IOException? confused by your question, you itself throw the exception and you are asking why?

Comment: The Exception is thrown by the Apache Poi Library and above is the code which throws it.

Comment: apache poi is not throwing the error, your code does throw "new IOException("Invalid header signature; read"

Comment: The HeaderBlockReader(InputStream stream) constructor is part of the Apache POI library. My code gets the existing xls file as a stream and then I want to create a new POIFileSystem with this InputStream.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just an idee, if you using maven make sure in the resource tag filtering is set to false.
Otherwise maven tends to corrupt xls files in the copying phase

Comment: in <resources> in your pom.xml

Answer (score 13):

That exception is telling you that your file isn't a valid OLE2-based .xls file.

Being able to open the file in Excel is no real guide - Excel will happily open any file it knows about no matter what the extension is on it. If you take a .csv file and rename it to .xls, Excel will still open it, but the renaming hasn't magically made it be in the .xls format so POI won't open it for you.

If you open the file in Excel and do Save-As, it'll let you write it out as a real Excel file. If you want to know what file it really is, try using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) - the Tika CLI with `--detect` ought to be able to tell you

.

How can I be sure it's not a valid file? If you look at the [OLE2 file format specification doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942138.aspx) from Microsoft, and head to [section 2.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941946.aspx) you'll see the following:

> Header Signature (8 bytes): Identification signature for the compound file structure, and MUST be set to the value 0xD0, 0xCF, 0x11, 0xE0, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0x1A, 0xE1.

Flip those bytes round (OLE2 is little endian) and you get 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0, the magic number from the exception. Your file doesn't start with that magic number, as so really isn't a valid OLE2 document, and hence POI gives you that exception.

Comment: Okay, opening in Excel and Save-As results in the same problem. Then I downloaded the Apache Tika jar and running it with the --detect option says: application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: Is your filesystem broken perhaps? Disk dying? See the updated answer, the file header you have really isn't valid!

Comment: To make it even weirder: when i read the same template file by directly adressing it at its location in the src/main/resources folder it works. However when i try to read it with getResourceAsStream() I get this invalid header value ...

Comment: Is something doing some odd utf8/ascii or native/unicode conversion on your stream perhaps? I can only suggest you create a small (~50 byte) test file, try loading that and compare the bytes, then ask a new question based on that!

Comment: Itrs very good explanation, @Gagravarr, Do you know how come Excel understands invalid OLE2 files and still can open it, while we cant parse the file using Apache POI programmatic manner?

Comment: @BhuvaneshMani Excel supports a wide range of file formats, not all of which are OLE2 based. Try using Apache Tika to find out what your file really is, then use the correct library for that!

Answer (score 0):

If your project is maven project, the following code may help:

```
/**
 * Get input stream of excel.
 * <p>
 *     Get excel from src dir instead of target dir to avoid causing POI header exception.
 * </p>
 * @param fileName file in dir PROJECT_PATH/src/test/resources/excel/ , proceeding '/' is not needed.
 * @return
 */
private static InputStream getExcelInputStream(String fileName){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try{
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(getProjectPath() + "/src/test/resources/excel/" + fileName);
    }catch (URISyntaxException uriE){
        uriE.printStackTrace();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException fileE){
        fileE.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inputStream;
}

private static String getProjectPath() throws URISyntaxException{
    URL url = YourServiceImplTest.class.getResource("/");
    Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
    Path subPath = path.subpath(0, path.getNameCount() -2);
    return "/" + subPath.toString();
}
```