# How to remove a row from an Excel (csv) file using Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv, apache-poi

I have a GUI program in which I write the personal details of people to an Excel spreadsheet saved as a CSV file. I can read and write to it just fine, however, I must be able to remove people from the file. My current code is down below:

```
JButton btnDeleteClient = new JButton("Delete Client");
        btnDeleteClient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Client deleteClient = null;
                 try {
                     String line = "";

                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Clients.csv"));
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            String[] data = line.split(",");
                            String clientName = data[0];
                            if(data.length > 1) {
                                clientName = clientName + " " + data[1];
                                if(clientName.equals(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem())){
                                    deleteClient = new Client(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7]);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (br != null) {
                            try {
                                br.close();
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 try {
                        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("Clients.csv"));
                        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
                        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                        Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                                    if (currentRow.getCell(2).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                                        if (currentRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue().compareTo(deleteClient.getEmail()) != 0) {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                   currentRow.getCell(0).setCellValue("");
                                   currentRow.getCell(1).setCellValue("");
                                   currentRow.getCell(2).setCellValue("");
                                   currentRow.getCell(3).setCellValue("");
                                   currentRow.getCell(4).setCellValue("");
                                   currentRow.getCell(5).setCellValue("");
                                   currentRow.getCell(6).setCellValue("");
                                   currentRow.getCell(7).setCellValue("");
                            }
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Clients.csv");
                        workbook.write(outputStream);
                        workbook.close();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
            }
        });
        btnDeleteClient.setBounds(463, 348, 120, 23);
        existingClients.add(btnDeleteClient);
```

When I run the program and click the delete button, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6C6F432C79657254, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:181)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:302)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:413)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:394)
    at IA$77.actionPerformed(IA.java:1837)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949792/invalid-header-reading-xls-file?

Comment: The `apache poi` supports either the Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Binary file format (BIFF8) `*.xls` using `HSSF` or the default XML-based file format for Excel from Excel 2007 upto actual versions `*.xlsx` using `XSSF`. But `HSSFWorkbook` does **not** directly support reading `CSV` which is a text format only.

Comment: I have. I also understand that there are multiple questions focused on similar questions to mine, however, I have not understood many of them or been able to apply their answers to my own and I would just be extremely grateful for a more personal response.

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton btnDeleteClient = new JButton("Delete Client");
    btnDeleteClient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                List<String[]> myEntries = new ArrayList<>();
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("Clients.csv"),',');
                myEntries = reader.readAll();
                List<String[]> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String[] row: myEntries){
                    if(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().equals(row[0]+" "+row[1])){
                        toRemove.add(row);
                    }
                }
                myEntries.removeAll(toRemove);
                CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("Clients.csv"), ',',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
                for(String[]row : myEntries){        
                    writer.writeNext(row);
                }        
                writer.close();                    
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: When I paste this code into my class, I am getting many errors. For example: readCsvFile has the following error: Illegal modifier for parameter readCsvFile; only final is permitted. And List has the following error: The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String[]>.

Comment: Ahhh, I thought I would need to download a jar file.

Comment: I downloaded "opencsv-3.10.jar" and imported it to Eclipse, however nothing has changed.