# How do I fix NotOLE2FileException error?

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv, apache-poi

I am trying to delete a specific row in an excel sheet using Java, however when I run the program i get the following error:

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6C6F432C79657254, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:181)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:302)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:413)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:394)
    at IA$77.actionPerformed(IA.java:1847)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I cannot post my code due to plagiarism purposes. However, the file I am reading from is a csv file and I am using POI to delete the row. I will explain my code, I use a while loop and a buffered reader and compare the data in the first cell of each row to what I am searching for, if the data matches, then I must delete this entire row. So once I have found the row, for each of the columns I use the following:

```
currentRow.getCell(0).setCellValue("");
```

Comment: To solve your question, lets repeat your answer again "However, the file I am reading from is a csv file ..."

Comment: `Apache poi` is not made to read `CSV` and create a `Workbook` from it. [But this was told you already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544419/how-to-remove-a-row-from-an-excel-csv-file-using-java).